# What happens if you poke a black hole with a stick?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

Suppose I'm hovering 1 meter away from the horizon of a Schwarzschild black hole and I'm holding a 2 meter long metal rod. Now I thrust the rod towards the horizon? What do I observe?

A satisfactory answer to this question needs to include a discussion of the following:

1. When the Schwarzschild radius is much larger than 1 meter.
2. When the Schwarzschild radius is much smaller than 1 meter.
3. What happens to the rod? Probably some time dilation happens and I can't actually see it going through the event horizon.
4. People often say that in a big enough black hole, the horizon isn't anything special because gravity isn't strong. But if I can't even move my stick by a meter, something really special must be happening?
5. If I can indeed observe the stick going through the horizon, what happens when I pull back on it?

Please ignore quantum effects. The question is labeled as a GR question, nothing else.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126929/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158195/

Comment: Re: "in a big enough black hole...gravity isn't strong." Don't conflate the _gradient_ of the gravity field with its absolute strength.  If the BH is sufficiently large, then you will not be spaghettified, _if you are in free fall_, because the force pulling your nose toward the center won't be hugely _different_ from the force pulling your toes, but in the scene that you describe, both of those forces will be astronomically, mind-bogglingly, incomprehensibly huge.

Comment: You'd need a stick of an infinite length to reach the event horizon from a hovering position. Space around a black hole is curved in such a way that it infinitely expands in the radial direction toward the event horizon according to the Schwarzschild metric.

Comment: @safesphere no it doesn't. The proper radial distance $s(r) = \int_{r_s}^r (1-r_s/r')^{-1/2}dr'$ for the Schwarzschild metric is finite. See [length contraction in a gravitational field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145264/length-contraction-in-a-gravitational-field).

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks John! I appreciate the clarification. So space does infinitely expand in the sense of $ds/dr\to\infty$, but the distance doesn't diverge. Interesting. I'll need to ponder what Kevin Brown meant here: "*a hovering observer* [...] *is actually a great distance (perhaps even light-years) from the $r = 2m$ boundary, even though he is just $1$ inch above*" - https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s7-03/7-03.htm