# Sphere of circumferential radius $r$

Tags: black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

What do you then mean by constructing a sphere of circumferential radius   $r$ centered on the black hole? Is that sphere a 2D surface?

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is as discussed in my answer to your previous question: [Angular coordinates are unaffected?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312056/angular-coordinates-are-unaffected)

The phrase *circumferential radius* means the radius you get by dividing the circumference of the sphere by $2\pi$ i.e. it is the Schwarzschild $r$ coordinate of the sphere.

The sphere is indeed a two dimensional manifold. That is the $r$ coordinate is fixed and the $t$ coordinate is ignored so points lying in the sphere can be labelled using just the $\theta$ and $\phi$ coordinates.